# Calculate Mean based on row and column conditions across multiple CSV files with removing NA data

Tags: loops, csv, dataframe, mean, rbind

I am working with data within over 300 csv files.  The variable column names are the same in each csv file.  I used rbind and loop to stack the columns into an empty data frame.  I want to calculate the mean of one column, but before I do this, I need to (1) subset or isolate a data frame based on values in another column.

Example:

Consider the following data frame called dfABC( )

```
A     B     C
1     5     7
1     4     6
4     5     8
2     5     7
2     1     7
3     2     3
```

I need to shrink the data frame according to values within a column.  Suppose I want the data frame shrunk according to column B.  Suppose I want to return all rows in which B = 5.  Then I would get this data frame:

```
A     B     C
1     5     7
4     5     8
2     5     7
```

From this new data frame (i.e., dfABC2( ) ), I will then be able to calculate the mean of Column A or C.

Additionally, there are NA values that I need to remove before calculating the mean.  Your help is appreciated.  I have tried various methods, but each method seems to return an error message of some sort and/or return a number that is incorrect according to what I should receive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
dataframeWothoutNAs <-na.omit(df)
```

To remove na values from the data frame.

You can use the `subset` function to perform the subsetting.

Here is a link with some different subsetting examples, some using subset function and some using other means (no pun intended)

http://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html

e.g.

```
subsetteddata <- subset(df, B == 5)
```